# Using pouchdb with python

Tags: python, django, couchdb, web2py, pouchdb

I am doing some research on taking a python app written in either django or web2py, and using it as a desktop app. And for a database, remotely I will be using couchdb for it's replication abilities. For the dektop, I need to find a way to integrate pouchdb into the app, but short of the homepage saying to include the pouchdb.js file, I can't find any docs on how to use it with python. And how to get setup in general for localhost to remote server syncing.

I was hoping someone could shed some light on how to get this accomplished. As for django/web2py, im not sure which one I want to use yet but have narrowed it down to those 2.

The idea for the app itself is that I have the website which has all the normal functionality available. And the user can install a package locally to their desktop from an installer. That local copy would have a subset of features from the website and sync some data from the pouchdb instance locally, to the remote server. enough to be able to fully interact with the db when offline.

Answer (score 4):

For this purpose I created [Python-PouchDB](http://python-pouchdb.marten-de-vries.nl) a few days ago. It runs PouchDB inside QtWebKit via either PyQt4, PyQt5 or PySide (you need to ship one of them with your app), and provides a nice (both synchronous and asynchronous) Python interface.

You can install it by executing:

```
pip install python-pouchdb
```

(or just by extracting the pouchdb directory from the source which you can find linked on the website.)

Example usage:

```
>>> import pouchdb
>>> environment = pouchdb.setup()
>>> db = environment.PouchDB("test")
>>> db.put({"_id": "mytest"})
{u'ok': True, u'rev': u'...', u'id': u'mytest'}
>>> db["mytest"] #shorthand for db.get()
{u'_rev': u'...', u'_id': u'mytest'}
>>> db.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

PouchDB runs on IndexedDB in the browser, with future plans for supporting WebSQL, but in general the idea is the it builds on local database capabilities provided by the browser.

If I understood right you want to be able to access it from Python? I don't think that's going to be possible, while finding a Python wrapper around a JavaScript engine might be possible, but you wouldn't be able to access the browser backed database.

You should also consider making a [CouchApp](http://couchapp.org/) instead, though that still won't give you the ability to use Django templates.

Basically the way you should structure your app is that it only uses JavaScript based templating (Mustache, Handlebars, etc etc) and interact with your API using a REST interface, so you don't have to have a Python engine running for the client side offline app. It might still be doable, but if you have to bundle tons of technologies with your app it will be a heavy download.

Comment: Yea couchapps are cool, but I dont think that would let me have the level of infrastructure that I will need for my app, since I will need a real desktop client. I may just have a setup script in my installer, that downloads and sets up couch for the end user, not sure yet.

Comment: Puchdb also wont work, since  I may need that data easily outside of the main client. Such as if we ever have other, external tools to manage or monitor the database.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was trying to say, if you want to access the database outside of the browser PouchDB is not for you. You can replicate it though, but you definitely not going to be able to build a Django app this way.